# EKS, ELB, Nginx Ingress - Right Combination for Sticky Sessions/Session Affinity and showing real Client IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

Trying to figure out what the right settings are, to be able to have the clients real IP show up in our logs, and for session affinity to work.

I am not getting the client IPs in the logs now, and if i move from 1 pod, to 2, I can no longer log in etc.  The nginx logs dont seem to have anything in them showing a problem.

Values.yml

```
controller:
  config:
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    use-proxy-protocol: "true"
    proxy-real-ip-cidr: "172.21.0.0/16"
  replicaCount: 2
  image:
    repository: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller
    tag: "0.28.0"
  ingressClass: ingress-internal
  publishService:
    enabled: true
  service:
    externalTrafficPolicy: Local
    targetPorts:
      http: 80
      https: http
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:523447765480:certificate/3972f84d-c167-43da-a207-8be0b955df48"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: "Name=idaas2-ingress-internal,cluster=idaas2,Environment=prd,Project=idaas2,Customer=idauto"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-enabled: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "True"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: "sg-02ca93f2fe8cbc950"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
```

Ingress Annotation

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ingress-internal
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    monitor.stakater.com/enabled: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header l5d-dst-override $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:$service_port;
      grpc_set_header l5d-dst-override $service_name.$namespace.svc.cluster.local:$service_port;
```

Im not even sure where to continue searching, I can provide any additional information required.

Comment: Why would you use sticky session in Kubernetes? That's dangerous and not a good idea... Session should be in cache, something like redis to prevent issues... Simple example, when cluster is scaling it will do a new pod repartition as it needs to do it (not always how you hope it to do)... it won't take into account stickyness and you will, most likely, lose session...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to fix the real client IP but I made the sticky sessions working with this in Ingress metadata:

```
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=1200
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
```

Answer (score 0):

I just increased my replica from 1 to 2, and got into the same situation. Because I do like a lot knowing from where the user on my application is based on (I don't want to go into Nginx controller logs to know its ip, I want to receive it by email sometimes hihi)

But now everything is OK (in 24 hours of thinking)

I am using proxy protocol v2 (to get the real IP) and session affinity both combined with Nginx.

I just give you a pick of my set up

```
helm upgrade nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set-string controller.config."use-gzip"="true",controller.config."http-redirect-code"="301",controller.config."use-proxy-protocol"="true",controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/scw-loadbalancer-proxy-protocol-v2"="true",controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/scw-loadbalancer-use-hostname"="true",controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/scw-loadbalancer-sticky-sessions"="cookie",controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/scw-loadbalancer-sticky-sessions-cookie-name"="route"
```

Then in you backend pod use these annotations

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "footballdata-scaleway"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
```

My cluster is on [scaleway.com](https://scaleway.com) by the way.

You hurt yourself making Kubernetes charts on you own. Switch to helm 3.